# calendar search spec is not working in jpql queries

Tags: java, jpa, calendar, jpql

unable to render a list by jpql search spec for calendar

<----myJpQl Query---->
(:createdDate is null or tu.taskID.created LIKE CONCAT('%',:createdDate,'%'))

where createdDate is of Calendar type.

Comment: you can add some more context to your question by mentioning the full query and relevant entity fields. It helps understand the problem quickly. Also, put the code/query in backticks so that it doesn't get mixed up with informational text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LIKE with a date!

With date usually between is used or you have to convert it to a string using a database function:

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/database-functions/